# Javascript - Nightmare.JS infinite scroll action

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll, nightmare

What am I doing wrong here? I want to scroll-down a page until the selector is gone.

```
    Nightmare.action('scrollPage', function (done) {
          this.evaluate_now(function () {
            var hitRockBottom = false; 
            while (!hitRockBottom) {
                // console.log("1");
            // Scroll the page (not sure if this is the best way to do so...)
            this.scrollTo(100000, 0);

            // Check if we've hit the bottom
            hitRockBottom = this.evaluate(function() {
                // console.log("0");
                return this.exists('selector') === null;
            }); }
          }, done)
        })
```

I'm using:

```
.goto("link")
.scrollPage()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Porting my original answer from [Nightmare #625](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/625).)

This is a **very** naive method to answer your question:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var vo = require('vo');
var nightmare = Nightmare({
  show: true
});

var run = function * () {
  yield nightmare.goto('http://someInfiniteScrollPage.tld');

  var previousHeight, currentHeight=0;
  while(previousHeight !== currentHeight) {
    previousHeight = currentHeight;
    var currentHeight = yield nightmare.evaluate(function() {
      return document.body.scrollHeight;
    });
    yield nightmare.scrollTo(currentHeight, 0)
      .wait(3000);
  }
  yield nightmare.end();
};

vo(run)(function(err) {
  console.dir(err);
  console.log('done');
});
```

This approach has problems: when you're going against a page that [actually is an *infinite* scroll](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/infinite_scrolling.html), the above will never end.  Also, the `.wait()` call could be replaced with waiting for the scroll element count to change to possibly reduce latency and increase robustness.  Still, this should be enough to get you started.

---

EDIT:  You asked about a selector, you could swap the `while` clause to use a selector instead of looking at increasing height.  From the hip, something like:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var vo = require('vo');
var nightmare = Nightmare({
  show: true
});

var run = function * () {
  yield nightmare.goto('http://someInfiniteScrollPage.tld');

  while(document.querySelectorAll('.someClass').length > 0) {
    var currentHeight = yield nightmare.evaluate(function() {
      return document.body.scrollHeight;
    });
    yield nightmare.scrollTo(currentHeight, 0)
      .wait(3000);
  }
  yield nightmare.end();
};

vo(run)(function(err) {
  console.dir(err);
  console.log('done');
});
```

This approach still has problems: for one, you're relying on the page to satisfy the `while` query, which isn't necessarily guaranteed.

Comment: I feel like I must be totally missing something - Does `document` actually refer to the page's `document` object? I was under the impression that it didn't work like that. And when I try to reference `document` in my code, I get a "document is not defined" error. ?

Comment: Also, it looks like the `while` loops in these examples loop very "tightly" (without the intended three second wait). Is that correct? All calls to NightmareJS are asynchronous, right?

Comment: Regarding the `while` loops - I'm guessing it has to do with using generators? I'm a generator newb; will look into it more.