# Lazy load scroll with nightmare JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I'm new to NightmareJS and wrote a script to scrape a website. 
This works like that. I login to my profile, wait for the site to load, then go to my likes profile and there I want to scroll down till the end of the site. At the moment I use this kind of ugly work around and wonder if there is a way to scroll down to the bottom of the page to get all results, and then go to the next step.

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var vo = require('vo');
vo(run)(function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
function *run() {
  var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true,
                             webPreferences: { partition: 'your-custom-partition'}});
    yield nightmare
    .goto('https://facebook.com/login')
    .type('input[id="email"]', "user")
    .type("input[id='pass']", "pass")
    .click('#loginbutton')
    .wait('._8u._42ef')
    .goto('https://www.facebook.com/myprofile/likes')
    .wait(1000)
    yield nightmare
    .evaluate(function() {
        window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
    })
    .wait(3000)
    .evaluate(function() {
        window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
    })
    .wait(3000)
    .evaluate(function() {
        window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
    })
    .wait(3000)
    .evaluate(function() {
        window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
    })
    .wait(3000)
        .evaluate(function() {
        window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
    })
    .wait(3000)
    .evaluate(function() {
        window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
    })
    .wait(3000)
    .evaluate(function() {
        window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
    })
    .wait(3000)
    .evaluate(function() {
        window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
    })
    .wait(3000)
        .evaluate(function() {
        window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
    })
    .wait(3000)
    .evaluate(function() {
        window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
    })
    .wait(3000)
    .evaluate(function() {
        window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
    })
    .wait(3000)
    .evaluate(function() {
        window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
    })
    .wait(3000)
        .evaluate(function() {
        window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
    })
    .wait(3000)
    .evaluate(function() {
        window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
    })
    .wait(3000)
    .evaluate(function() {
        window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
    })
    .wait(3000)
    .evaluate(function() {
        window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
    })
    .wait(3000)
  var title = yield nightmare
    .evaluate(function() {
              var jsonObject = new Array('');
              var links = document.getElementsByClassName("_5rz _5k3a _5rz3 _1v6c");
              var numProfiles = links.length;
                for(var i = 0; i< numProfiles; i++){
                var elem;
                elem = links[i].querySelector(".fsl.fwb.fcb a").href;
                console.log(elem);
                jsonObject.push(elem);
              }
              if(numProfiles > 0) {
              //then delete that element, so we don't overlaod the page
              for(var j = 0; j < numProfiles; j++){
                links[0].parentNode.removeChild(links[0]);
                }
                window.document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
              }
              return jsonObject;
    });
  console.log(title);
  yield nightmare.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're after is something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090854/javascript-nightmare-js-infinite-scroll-action/37417956#37417956), which is related to [segmentio/nightmare#625](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/625).

For completeness, a copy of the solution provided in the referenced answers is included below.

---

This is a **very** naive method to answer your question:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var vo = require('vo');
var nightmare = Nightmare({
  show: true
});

var run = function * () {
  yield nightmare.goto('http://someInfiniteScrollPage.tld');

  var previousHeight, currentHeight=0;
  while(previousHeight !== currentHeight) {
    previousHeight = currentHeight;
    var currentHeight = yield nightmare.evaluate(function() {
      return document.body.scrollHeight;
    });
    yield nightmare.scrollTo(currentHeight, 0)
      .wait(3000);
  }
  yield nightmare.end();
};

vo(run)(function(err) {
  console.dir(err);
  console.log('done');
});
```

This approach has problems: when you're going against a page that [actually is an *infinite* scroll](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/infinite_scrolling.html), the above will never end.  Also, the `.wait()` call could be replaced with waiting for the scroll element count to change to possibly reduce latency and increase robustness.  Still, this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, that's an awesome solution. Do you have any tips how to detect an element that appeard that was not there before and which triggers to go to the next block?